# How to get bitcoin address from the pubkey_hash using bitcoin-abe or something else?

Tags: address, script, hash, python

I'm using: https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe to import the blockchain into a mysql DB it is almost done after 5 days. So I started looking at the data and didn't see any addresses. I know the BTC client doesn't use those, but it still would be nice to have them in another table. I was looking around at the code and found this:

```
def hash_to_address(version, hash):
    vh = version + hash
    return base58.b58encode(vh + double_sha256(vh)[:4])
```

In: https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe/blob/3004fe4bad6f64d4c032c735ee23bf9f052d825b/Abe/util.py

When I run a pubkey_hash through that function I don't get the expected result of an address. For example taking the following pubkey_hash: 62E907B15CBF27D5425399EBF6F0FB50EBB88F18

I should get: 1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa

But instead I get: 6GEZdxx5UiTk3U3LaLfsWwRaFAvXEpPNS5R4mqsJDXVJcTNNngTyB5i9S76MLTq

The script I created is:

```
import util
hash = '62E907B15CBF27D5425399EBF6F0FB50EBB88F18'
print util.hash_to_address("00", hash)
```

Any ideas?